# Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost: 3306 with user root. Host '::1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I install a workbench 8.0 in OS X, and I have two different version of MySQL installed already 5.6 which is the default installation and a 5.7.25 version, I switch in the System Preference to 5.7.25 version.
My root user in MySQL looks like this:

```
mysql> SELECT host FROM mysql.user WHERE User = 'root';
+-----------+
| host      |
+-----------+
| localhost |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I try to change the configuration in workbench to use localhost instead of 127.0.0.1 prompts the same error:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost: 3306 with user root. 
Host '::1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

Comment: Could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server?

Comment: Yeah, it works also, for some reason the security is set  in a way root can not be used set the connection, so I create a new user with all the privileges and it works.

Comment: Have you tried using an IPv4 address for localhost?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your `hosts` file so it not include hostname `localhost` for IPv6. You can make it like:

```
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1  localhost6
```

Or you can use IP address (127.0.0.1) to connect your MySQL instance